# How can I convert 4digit number a single digit number in Android

Tags: android

I had a edit text, in the edit text I used to enter a 4digit number and I have set some keys and value pair to 0-9 numbers.

So my question is when ever I enter a 4 number(any no of digits) in the edittext it should be converted into a single digit number so that the message in the `keyvalue` should appear.

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     String Sequence;
     Button buttonok;
     String UserEntreredNumber;
     HashMap<String,String> messagesMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
     String magicMessage;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText Sequence = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.Sequence);    

        Sequence.setError("Input must be 4 digits");



        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setPositiveButton(" ok ",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                dialog.cancel();
          }
        });

        //create hash map

       populateList(); 

        //populate hash map with 0 to 9 key and values


        buttonok=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.buttonok);
        buttonok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                UserEntreredNumber = Sequence.getText().toString();
                magicMessage = messagesMap.get(UserEntreredNumber);

                builder.setMessage( magicMessage);
                builder.show();         
        }
    });     

}
    private void populateList() { 

       messagesMap.put("0", "Congratulations!!!, you have been selected."); 
       messagesMap.put("1", "Wow! your program just ran without errors!"); 
       messagesMap.put("2", "It's very hot in office"); 
       messagesMap.put("3", "Wow, what a building? It's awesome");
       messagesMap.put("4", "You got a calll");
       messagesMap.put("5", "There were no errors");
       messagesMap.put("6", "U have been shortlisted for the next round");
       messagesMap.put("7", "nice costume");
       messagesMap.put("8", "do u have any idea!");
       messagesMap.put("9", "Today is a bad day");    
    }   
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain clearly ? Confusing with **when ever i enter a 4 number(any no of digits) in the edittext it should be converted into a single digit number**

Comment: Do you want the input to always be between 1000 and 9999 ?  Those are all four digit numbers. If that is the case, you can check that the string is indeed 4 characters long, attempt to convert it to an integer, if it converts, check the size.

Comment: @Ewald can u provide me some code...

Comment: The question is unclear.  Explain what exactly you need.  Say, give some examples of the inputs and outputs, and what you have tried so far

Comment: Seems @Evos beat me to it :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would help you:

```
Integer digit; 
try{
   digit = Integer.valueOf(Sequence.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException e){
   digit = null;
}
if (digit != null && digit >= 0 && digit <= 9999 && Pattern.matches("^[0-9]{4,4}$", Sequence.getText().toString());){
     //some logic
} else {
   Sequence.setError("Input must be 4 digits");
}
```

Comment: You might want to watch out for exceptions if you aren't restricting the user from entering anything but 0-9 characters.

Comment: but i am getting a error as 
The method valueOf(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (Editable)

Comment: Sorry,my mistake, i have fixed my code, please check it one more time.

Comment: but the 4 digit number should be converted into a single digit because i have written a keyvalue pair for 0-9 numbers(as i cannot write the keyvalue pair to all the numbers from 1000 and 9999)

Comment: @Abhinai check it one more time.

Comment: i was not getting the desired output for a 4digit number

Comment: And what is you desired output?

Comment: the 4 digit number should be converted into a single digit number and it should display a value in the keyvalue pair

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> the 4 digit number should be converted into a single digit number

If that is what you want then take the remainder of the division of the 4 digit number by 10 i.e the result of the operation:

`your 4 digit number % 10`

It will return a number between 0 to 9: actually the last digit of the 4 digit number.

---

Say your 4 digit number is in the variable digit4:

```
Integer digit4 = Integer.valueOf(Sequence.getText().toString());
```

Then you can get a single digit number between 0 to 9 (actually the last digit of the 4 digit number) in variable digit1 by:

```
                int digit1 = digit4 % 10;
```

---

You have not specified the relation between the 4 digit and single digit number, so if you want a random number between 0 t0 9 irrespective of the input you can get it using [public int nextInt (int n)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) method like:

```
Random r= new Random();
int digit1 = r.nextInt(10);
```